# dtexec processstartInfo

Tags: sql-server, ssis

What is maximum size of packagevariables for DTEXEC ProcessStartInfo while executing form C#(Process.start())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik maximum length of a process command line is 32k, as it falls into the [Environment Block limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686206(VS.85).aspx). However if a batch is involved then the cmd.exe's own limit of 8191 comes into play, see [Command prompt (Cmd. exe) command-line string limitation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473).